# Splice two different dataframes based on similar value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes with different dimensions. Lets say it´s displacement measurements but the readings are slightly different values and one has more data. Looks like this:

df1

| Index | displacement |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 0 |

df2

| Index | displacement | other data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 5 |
| 2 | 0.4 | 6 |
| 3 | 0.9 | 7 |
| 4 | 1.3 | 8 |
| 5 | 1.8 | 9 |
| 6 | 2.4 | 10 |

I want to add the "other data" to the first dataframe (df1), by looking for similar displacement value in df2 and asociating displacement value. In this case, the output i want must be similar to this:

df1

| Index | displacement | other data (from df2) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 | 9 |

And to keep adding the "other data" from df2. I dont know if pd.merge will work and im thinking maybe with a loop till displacement is higher than what im looking from and add the data from the previous row, but df2 has 10 times more rows than df1 and if the displacement measurement is the same as the one from a previous row it may not work. Any help in a cleaner/easier way to do it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should give a threshold for judging similar displacement values.

Answer (score 2):

I used the **merge_asof** function to find the nearest value base on two DataFrames' **displacement** columns, and then filtered the resulting DataFrame by a threshold.

```
df1['displacement'] =df1['displacement'].astype(float)
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates('displacement', keep='last')

df_out = pd.merge_asof(
    df1.sort_values("displacement"),
    df2.sort_values("displacement").assign(df2_displacement=lambda d: d["displacement"]),
    on="displacement",
    direction="nearest",
)

threshold = .5
dfout1 = df_out[abs(df_out['displacement'] -df_out['df2_displacement'] )< threshold ]
```

[image]

Comment: I think you could also use the `tolerance=0.5` keyword argument to do the comparison within `.merge_asof` (you probably have to drop some `NaN` rows afterwards).

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm gonna give it a try and see if it works

Comment: Just one question, here you are droping duplicates in df1, but the thing is i need to keep all the data. For example, df1 goes from 0 to 4 and back to zero, but so does df2 just with a different increase, so i dont want the second "2" displacement at index 4 in df1 get merged with the first df2 displacement that reaches close to "2".